# Django: Problem with Understanding Super Save Function

Tags: python, django

I am a beginner in Django. I am building a Django app, named PhoneReview. It will store reviews related to the latest mobile phone. It will also display phone brands, along with the associated phone models.

Right now, I am facing a problem understanding this code:

```
def save(self):
    super(Review, self).save()
    self.slug = '%i-%s' % (
        self.id, slugify(self.game.title)
    )
    super(Review, self).save()
```

It comes from **models.py**:

```
from django.db import models
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify

# Create your models here.
class Tag(models.Model):
    label = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.label

class Game(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    developer = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    platform = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='null')
    label_tag = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150, default='null')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

class Review(models.Model):
    game = models.ForeignKey(Game, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    review = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150, default='null')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.review

    def save(self):
        super(Review, self).save()
        self.slug = '%i-%s' % (
            self.id, slugify(self.game.title)
        )
        super(Review, self).save()
```

It looks like the `save` function is saving the slug. But I don't understand it completely. Is it converting integer to string? What is `super` doing here? Would you please give me a complete explanation about the `save` function?

Comment: Did you write the code or are following a tutorial? Why are you calling the `super().save` before and after the slug definition, and not only after like in the save method of the `Game` class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you overwrite a function (of a class) you can call the function of the parent class using `super`. The `save` function in the models records the instance in the database.
The first `super(Review, self).save()` is to obtain an id since it is generated automatically when an instance is saved in the database. The second is to record the changes in the field slug.